# Llamar formulario una sola vez

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo dos formularios, formulario1 y formulario2. El usuario debe ingresar ciertos datos en el formulario1, en textboxes, y se debe confirmar el dato ingresado, pero yo lo hago con otro formulario (formulario2), el cual tiene 1 textbox y 2 botones (confirmar y cancelar), y "aparece" al frente del textbox en cuestión al intentar salir del textbox. El proceso es el siguiente:

Entra a textbox1 -> Intenta salir de texbox1, aparece formulario2 solicitando confirmar el dato. Si la confirmación es correcta, pasa a textbox2, de otra forma se queda en formulario2. Si oprime Cancelar regresa a texbox1.

El punto es que son 4 textboxes anidados, así que debe "saltar" del texbox1 al texbox2, y al texbox3, y al textbox4.

Y funciona, pero no correctamente. Los siguientes son los métodos en formulario1

```
void txtCopias_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SacaTotal();
            Point locationOnForm = txtCopias.FindForm().PointToClient(txtCopias.Parent.PointToScreen(txtCopias.Location));
            using (ConfirmaContadores confConta = new ConfirmaContadores(int.Parse(txtCopias.Text)))
            {
                confConta.Location = new Point(locationOnForm.X, locationOnForm.Y + 25);
                var respuesta=confConta.ShowDialog();
                if (respuesta == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    txtCopias.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtImpresion.Focus();
                }
                //confConta.Dispose();
            }
        }

        void txtImpresion_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SacaTotal();
            Point locationOnForm = txtImpresion.FindForm().PointToClient(txtImpresion.Parent.PointToScreen(txtImpresion.Location));
            using (ConfirmaContadores confContadores = new ConfirmaContadores(int.Parse(txtImpresion.Text)))
            {
                confContadores.Location = new Point(locationOnForm.X, locationOnForm.Y + 25);
                confContadores.ShowDialog();
                var respuesta = confContadores.ShowDialog();
                if (respuesta == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    txtImpresion.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtEscaner.Focus();
                }
                //confContadores.Dispose();
            }
        }

        void txtEscaner_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SacaTotal();
            Point locationOnForm = txtEscaner.FindForm().PointToClient(txtEscaner.Parent.PointToScreen(txtEscaner.Location));
            using (ConfirmaContadores confirmaConta = new ConfirmaContadores(int.Parse(txtEscaner.Text)))
            {
                confirmaConta.Location = new Point(locationOnForm.X, locationOnForm.Y + 25);
                confirmaConta.ShowDialog();
                var respuesta = confirmaConta.ShowDialog();
                if (respuesta == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    txtEscaner.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtFax.Focus();
                }
                //confirmaConta.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Y formulario2 tiene estos métodos:

```
private void btnConfirmar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (int.Parse(txtContadores.Text) == _contador)
            {
                DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Los datos ingresados no coinciden. Favor de verificar.", "Error en captura", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            Dispose();
        }
```

Como pueden ver, los `Dispose();` los tengo en formulario2 (leí que cuando son formularios modales el Dispose() es manual). De esta forma, el texbox1 funciona correctamente, pero al intentar salir del texbox2 me marca `Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.ObjectDisposedException'`.
Igual para pasar del texbox2 al 3 y del 3 al 4.
Entonces pensé en `Dispose();` desde formulario1, borré los `Dispose();` de formulario2 y los puse en formulario1 (ahí donde se ven comentados) pero de esta forma, por alguna razón, a partir del textbox2 no me respeta el clic en el botón Confirmar (debo clicarlo 2 veces para que cierre el form2).

¿Alguien podría explicarme por qué hace eso, y cómo podría solucionarlo?

¡Gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: Buff...es un poco lio la pregunta. De donde sacaste que necesitas ejecutar `Dispose` en tu aplicación? Porque no entiendo para que lo estás utilizando. Resumiendo...que ocurre si quitas todos los `Dispose` que tienes? Que efecto crees que tiene `Dispose` en tu formulario?

Comment: Cerrar formulario2 y liberar los recursos utilizados. Al parecer no sucede nada quitando todos los `Dispose()`, pero como comenté, leí que los form modales no se "eliminan" solos, hay que hacerles `Dispose()` para que se liberen los recursos.
Ya los quité y el comportamiento sigue siendo el mismo, a partir del texbox2 debo dar clic 2 veces en el boton para que se cierre formulario2

Comment: Estoy en el movil ahora y no puedo responderte todo como quisiera. No se donde leiste eso,con `Close` debe liberarse cualquier recurso del formulario.

Comment: Sólo para que no crean que lo invento, en el siguiente enlace dice que cuando llamas a form.ShowDialog() debes invocar manualmente el Dispose(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097364/c-sharp-form-close-vs-form-dispose

Comment: Bueno,yo nunca lo había leido y la verdad tampoco creo que sea muy importante en este caso. Lee de todas maneras el ultimo comentario de la respuesta aceptada que dice todo lo contrario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya me di cuenta dónde está el problema: en los métodos `txtImpresion_Leave`, `txtEscaner_Leave`, `txtFax_Leave` tengo una línea extra, `confContadores.ShowDialog();`, que hace mostrar dos veces la ventana de confirmación...

Gracias a todos los que se dieron tiempo de leer el post.